# bootstrap edit modal not getting value

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

Hi my bootstrap edit modal is not getting two values it should be getting from the database.It should be getting Last Name and License Number Values and place it as a default value when I open the edit modal. Same as the other four. [Refer to this image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNaYd.png) Here are the codes..

**index.php**

```
<!-- edit modal -->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="editMemberModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit Member</h4>
      </div>

    <form class="form-horizontal" action="php_action/update.php" method="POST" id="updateMemberForm">         

      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="edit-messages"></div>

          <div class="form-group"> 
            <label for="editName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9"> 
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editName" name="editName" placeholder="Name">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="editLastName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editlName" name="editlName" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="editLicenseNumber" class="col-sm-3 control-label">License Number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editlNumber" name="editlNumber" placeholder="License Number">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="editAddress" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editAddress" name="editAddress" placeholder="Address">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="editContact" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Contact</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editContact" name="editContact" placeholder="Contact">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="editActive" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Paid</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <select class="form-control" name="editActive" id="editActive">
                <option value="">~~SELECT~~</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                <option value="2">No</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer editMemberModal">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<!-- /edit modal -->
```

**getSelectedMember.php**

```
$memberId = $_POST['member_id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = $memberId";

$query = $connect->query($sql);

$result = $query->fetch_assoc();

$connect->close();

echo json_encode($result);
```

**index.js**

```
function editMember(id = null) {
if(id) {

    // remove the error 
    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
    $(".text-danger").remove();
    // empty the message div
    $(".edit-messages").html("");

    // remove the id
    $("#member_id").remove();

    // fetch the member data
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php_action/getSelectedMember.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {member_id : id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {
            $("#editName").val(response.name);

            $("#editlName").val(response.lname);

            $("#editlNumber").val(response.lnumber);

            $("#editAddress").val(response.address);

            $("#editContact").val(response.contact);

            $("#editPaid").val(response.paid);  

            // mmeber id 
            $(".editMemberModal").append('<input type="hidden" name="member_id" id="member_id" value="'+response.id+'"/>');

            // here update the member data
            $("#updateMemberForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
                // remove error messages
                $(".text-danger").remove();

                var form = $(this);

                // validation
                var editName = $("#editName").val();
                var editlName = $("#editlName").val();
                var editlNumber = $("#editlNumber").val();
                var editAddress = $("#editAddress").val();
                var editContact = $("#editContact").val();
                var editPaid = $("#editPaid").val();

                if(editName == "") {
                    $("#editName").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $("#editName").after('<p class="text-danger">The Name field is required</p>');
                } else {
                    $("#editName").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                    $("#editName").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');              
                }

                if(editlName == "") {
                    $("#editlName").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $("#editlName").after('<p class="text-danger">The LastName field is required</p>');
                } else {
                    $("#editlName").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                    $("#editlName").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');             
                }

                if(editlNumber == "") {
                    $("#editlNumber").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $("#editlNumber").after('<p class="text-danger">The License Number field is required</p>');
                } else {
                    $("#editlNumber").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                    $("#editlNumber").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');               
                }

                if(editAddress == "") {
                    $("#editAddress").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $("#editAddress").after('<p class="text-danger">The Address field is required</p>');
                } else {
                    $("#editAddress").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                    $("#editAddress").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');               
                }

                if(editContact == "") {
                    $("#editContact").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $("#editContact").after('<p class="text-danger">The Contact field is required</p>');
                } else {
                    $("#editContact").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                    $("#editContact").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');               
                }

                if(editPaid == "") {
                    $("#editPaid").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $("#editPaid").after('<p class="text-danger">The Paid field is required</p>');
                } else {
                    $("#editPaid").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                    $("#editPaid").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');              
                }

                if(editName && editlName && editlNumber && editAddress && editContact && editPaid) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: form.attr('action'),
                        type: form.attr('method'),
                        data: form.serialize(),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success:function(response) {
                            if(response.success == true) {
                                $(".edit-messages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                                  '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                                  '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                                '</div>');

                                // reload the datatables
                                manageMemberTable.ajax.reload(null, false);
                                // this function is built in function of datatables;

                                // remove the error 
                                $(".form-group").removeClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
                                $(".text-danger").remove();
                            } else {
                                $(".edit-messages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                                  '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                                  '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                                '</div>')
                            }
                        } // /success
                    }); // /ajax
                } // /if

                return false;
            });

        } // /success
    }); // /fetch selected member info
```

Comment: What is the structure of the members table, do the field names tie up?

Comment: Yes, I have a add modal to database and everything is working fine there.

Comment: if you print out `response.lnumber` and `response.lname` from your ajax success function, do you get the expected values? If this is true we can rule out your server as the problem